# Multiple cases, each having multiple time seies

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

I have multiple cases, each having multiple independent variables measured over time. One of the variables represents known failure/success in the past, and I am trying to model a binary logistic regression to predict future failure/success (DV).

1. Am I barking under the wrong tree?
2. What will be the best model to move forward?

Thanks,

Joseph